# Check if variable contains pound sign javascript (HTML might be converting £ to a special entity number)

Tags: javascript

It seems that HTML is converting the pound sign to those non-sense syntax so when I try to do the check using JavaScript its no longer the syntax £. At least that's my theory, but I'm not sure if that is the case)

I tried:

```
if(variable.indexOf("£") >=0){
   /*do something*/
}

if(variable.charAt(0)==="£"){
   /*do something*/
 }
```

None of the above worked.

Is there a special way to do this?

Comment: can you try variable.match(/[£]/);

Comment: non-sense syntax? What would that be?

Comment: @espascarello https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp those syntax

Comment: so it is not nonsense.... lol.... that is what happens to properly parsed code. So where are you reading it from, why are you not checking for the entity if that is what you have?

Comment: Were are you getting the string from, HTML can use the `&pound;`

Comment: Working for me https://jsfiddle.net/obgg01qc/

Comment: And I wouldn't use `===`. You just want to know if the value is the same, you don't care about the type, use `==`.

Comment: @espascarello its just a figure speech because im annoyed with it.

Comment: @Keith I tried that

Comment: @Marvel308 it seems to have worked but i havent fully tested yet :)

Comment: @Luke if you're annoyed with that you should thank god you're not spanish, as you'd  die of seeing `&aacute;` and stuff like that for special characters

Comment: @Shinratensei  I would actually say `===` is the better option.  Faster evaluation, and less Linting warnings..

Comment: @Keith well it might be the case in this situation, just that I've heard javascript is that kind of languages that modifies the type of your variable if it feels like it

Comment: @Shinratensei You are right, but you have just remembered it the wrong way round.  `===` does no type coercion, but `==` will.  99% of the time, `===` is the best option.  The other 1% might be were you really do want `10 and "10" be equal`.  etc.

Comment: @Keith I just checked it here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp it's as I said, unless I'm terribly blind today

Comment: @Shinratensei `it's as I said,`  in what way?.   A better place to look -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness  `== equal to`  this is wrong anyway,  `== loose equality`.  IOW: if you use `==` Javascript is going to do type conversions, were as `===` will not.  From what I can gather w3schools doesn't have a great rep here on SO, so errors like that wouldn't be unusual..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DOMParser to get them back to characters:

```js
var span = document.getElementById('span');
var variable = span.innerText;
console.log(variable);

var parser = new DOMParser;
var start = parser.parseFromString('<!doctype html><body>'+variable,'text/html');
var end = start.body.textContent;

if(variable.indexOf("£") >=0){
   console.log("I have £");
}

if(variable.charAt(0)==="$"){
   console.log("I have $");
}
```

```html
<span id="span">&dollar;Me &amp; my friends have a lot of &pound; and &dollar;</span>
```

Comment: Thanks that really made my day much easier :)

Comment: @Luke Glad to help :).